# AngularJS : How to get http data in differents controllers

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-service, angularjs-controller

when I submit a form I have a controller that communicates with a service, which gets data from a server and return these data to the controller. Meanwhile, I change view with the form action. My problem is that I'd need the server response data in the second view (which has an another controller), but these are undefined. How can I fix this problem?

Ps. I'm sorry for my English

```
// code...
.state('app.search', {
  url: "/search",
  views: {
    'menuContent' :{
      templateUrl: "templates/search.html",
          controller: 'SearchCtrl'
    }
  }
})

.state('app.result', {
  url: "/result",
  views: {
    'menuContent' :{
      templateUrl: "templates/result.html",
      controller: "ResultCtrl",
     }
  }
})
// code...

<form name="search_form" ng-submit="searchLines()" action="#/app/result" novalidate>
  // code...
</form>

.factory('Bus', function($http){
return{
    get: function(callback){ 
        $http({
            method: "POST",
            url: "someUrl",
            headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}, 
            data: {someData from the form}
        })
        .success(function(data) { 
            callback(data);
        })
        .error(function(data, status, error) { 
            console.log(data, status, error);
        });
    }
}
});

.controller('SearchCtrl', function($scope, Bus){
    $scope.searchLines = function(){
        Bus.get(function(data){
          $scope.company = data.company; // this is ok
        }); 
     };
})

.controller('ResultCtrl', function($scope, Bus){
    // I'd like to have $scope.company here
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a `service` for that. 
`Controllers` **shouldn't** hold state.
Two `controllers` can communicate via a `service`(the `service` will hold the state as well).

Add a company variable on the Bus `service` and add a **getter** so other `controllers` can fetch the data from Bus.

Example:

HTML:

```
<div ng-app="app">
    <div ng-controller="aCtrl">{{model.stateA}}</div>
    <div ng-controller="bCtrl">{{model.stateB}}</div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.service('myService', function ($q) {
    var state = "12312";

    this.getStateFromServer = function () {
        return $q.when(state);
    }

    this.getRealState = function(){
        return state;
    };
});

app.controller('aCtrl', function ($scope, myService) {
    myService.getStateFromServer().then(function (res) {
        $scope.model = {
            stateA: "A" + myService.getRealState()
        };
    });
});


app.controller('bCtrl', function ($scope, myService) {
    $scope.model = {stateB: "B" + myService.getRealState()};
});
```

[`JSFIDDLE`](http://jsfiddle.net/ztg9b3s7/).

Comment: In this way I get the same result...it's because I've putted Bus.set() into a $scope function?
ex. $scope.searchLines = function(){
   Bus.set(departure, arrival, time1, time2, date)
    .then(function (res) {
        $scope.company = {
            stateA: "A" + Bus.get()
        };
    });

Comment: And I get this error too: "Cannot read property 'then' of undefined"

Comment: With "$scope.model = {stateB: "B" + Bus.get()};
    console.log($scope.model);" I only get "B"...can't figure out

Comment: I do it... if I change view after Bus.set()?

Comment: I dont understand you. I've created two working codes for you. One from scratch and the other based on your code. simply compare them and see what's different.
in your set method you need to add a return before the $http.